# solana getParsedProgramAccounts 410 gone?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js

i have a code that was working very well, and suddenly, this rpc call is not working anymore.
I'm on the mainnet api, it looks like they have disabled this rpc call, because i have now a result with error "410 gone"

BTW : i tried serum api also but there is an error (504 Gateway Time-out)

Anyone having the same issue ? Or anyone knows how to do that correctly now ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the public rpc, https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com, it is heavily rate limited and doesn't allow for some calls, just as getParsedProgramAccounts on anything Metaplex related.

Recommended to get a private RPC if you're doing heavy work calls such as `getProgramAccounts`. GenesysGo, quicknode, and many more offer great services.

At the time of writing, GenesysGo's full rpc is free at https://ssc-dao.genesysgo.net

Comment: I'm wondering, since @frédéric-bry it was working fine until recently, is there any statement from the solana or project serum team on new/changed restrictions?